# Rails methods called during a database change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Basically i want to update a set of caches when data is created/removed/amended from a table

what would the most pragmatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has a set of callbacks ([more info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)).
I would use the after_commit callback to invalidate your caches.

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :invalidate_cache

  private
    def invalidate_cache
      #some logic
    end
end
```